# DirectionalLight lighting pinned to one side of glTF, even when glTF is rotated

Tags: three.js

I have a DirectionalLight that seems to work for basic glTF objects, but my main character glTF has an odd result: when she is rotated, the DirectionalLight light appears to be pinned in front of her. Notice how the tent (prism-shaped thing) in this scene has the correct lighting, but the character does not:

[image]

It's as if the light is rotating with her:

[image]

I don't know what else to check. Things I've checked:
- the camera has updateMatrixWorld each frame
- the DirectionalLight position and target.position have updateMatrixWorld each frame

What else should I be looking for?

EDIT: Could it be something to do with normals on this particular animated glTF?

Comment: Did you add the light programmatically via Three.js, or was it included in the GLTF? If it was included in the GLTF, then the rotation may be affecting the model and the light simultaneously because they're grouped together in the hierarchy.

Comment: I added it programmatically. (That was my thought too--but I just double checked the children of the scene and there are no light objects).

Comment: It could be a number of other things. Maybe it's colored via vertexColors or some sort of baked-in emissive map? I would need to see your code. Have you tried dragging the GLTF to the editor to see how it looks there? https://threejs.org/editor/